# Unable to sign SoapMessage in C#

Tags: c#, xml, digital-signature

I want to sign a xml with every time i got a message: Invalid Reference-element on the line:             signedXml.ComputeSignature();  If i sign with URI="" then i have no errors. But if i specifiy an id i have.
Can someone help me?

I tried this code:

public static void SignSoapMessage(XmlDocument soapEnvelope, X509Certificate2 certificate, Excel.Workbook wbTest)

```
        RSA privateKey = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();
        // Create a SignedXml object
        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(soapEnvelope);

        // Assign the key to the SignedXml object.
        signedXml.SigningKey = privateKey;

        // Create a reference to be signed.
        System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.Reference reference = new System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.Reference();
        reference.Uri = "#id-2832";

        // Add the reference to the SignedXml object
        signedXml.AddReference(reference);

        KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
        KeyInfoX509Data keyInfoData = new KeyInfoX509Data();
        keyInfo.AddClause(keyInfoData);
        signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

        // Add transforms 
        reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
        reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigC14NTransform());

        reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"; // Specify the digest algorithm

        signedXml.ComputeSignature();
        XmlElement signatureElement = signedXml.GetXml();
        soapEnvelope.DocumentElement.AppendChild(signatureElement);

    private string GenerateSOAPRequest(string xbrlDocument, string binarySecurityToken, X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {

        string publicKey = Convert.ToBase64String(certificate.GetPublicKey());


        string soapEnvelope = $@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:ns=""http://logius.nl/digipoort/koppelvlakservices/1.2/"" xmlns:wsse=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"" xmlns:wsu=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"">
    <soapenv:Header wsu:Id=""header-id"" xmlns:wsa=""http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"">
        <wsse:Security>
                {binarySecurityToken}
            <!-- Add Timestamp -->
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id=""timestamp-id"">
                <wsu:Created>{DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")}</wsu:Created>
                    <wsu:Expires>{DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")}</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
        <wsa:Action wsu:Id=""id-2831"">http://logius.nl/digipoort/wus/2.0/aanleverservice/1.2/AanleverService/aanleverenRequest</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:ReplyTo wsu:Id=""id-2832"">
            <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address>
        </wsa:ReplyTo>
        <wsa:MessageID wsu:Id=""id-2830"">uuid:0a528087-4b2e-4d89-ba5d-a0168b344f04</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:To wsu:Id=""id-2829"">https://preprod-dgp.procesinfrastructuur.nl/wus/2.0/aanleverservice/1.2</wsa:To>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body wsu:Id=""id-2828"">
        <ns:aanleverRequest xmlns:ns=""http://logius.nl/digipoort/koppelvlakservices/1.2/"">
            <ns:berichtsoort>Jaarrekening</ns:berichtsoort>
            <ns:aanleverkenmerk>{KVKnummer}_{EindDatumGeconverteerd}</ns:aanleverkenmerk>
            <ns:identiteitBelanghebbende>
                <ns:nummer>{KVKnummer}</ns:nummer>
                <ns:type>KvK</ns:type>
            </ns:identiteitBelanghebbende>
            <ns:rolBelanghebbende>Intermediair</ns:rolBelanghebbende>
            <ns:berichtInhoud>
                <ns:mimeType>application/xml</ns:mimeType>
                <ns:bestandsnaam>{KVKnummer}_{EindDatumGeconverteerd}.xbrl</ns:bestandsnaam>
                <ns:inhoud>{Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xbrlDocument))}</ns:inhoud>
            </ns:berichtInhoud>
        </ns:aanleverRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>";

        return soapEnvelope;
    }
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257174/discussion-on-question-by-daan1986-unable-to-sign-soapmessage-in-c); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.